# Disable mousemovement event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, fullpage.js

I'm using jquery.fullpage.js but am seeing a strange bug in IE 10. When I move the mouse the page scrolls up or down.

Here is how I initialize jquery.fullpage.js

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({});
```

Is there anyway I can disable the `mousemovement` event, or do you have a fix for jquery.fullpage.js?

Comment: not being intentionally troll-y, but from a UX standpoint, it's usually a horrible idea to hijack much of anything and much less mouse movement. Have you viewed their demo page in IE10? Same result? If not, what are they doing differently?

Comment: It's the same with their demopage

Comment: @Todd it's not always a bad idea... or at least thats not what companies like Apple, Facebook, Sony, Flickr, Tumblr or MediaFire think about it. There are good and bad uses of that technique.

Comment: I can appreciate that -- absolutely. At the same time, the appeal to their popularity doesn't make it any less frustrating and imo unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$(document).on('mousemove',function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Well it was worth a shot.  Sounds like you have a legitimate bug here... I don't have IE10 but don't see any issue in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could also be worth a shot:

```
$(document).on('mousemove MSPointerMove',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested Windows 7 and IE 10 in http://www.browserstack.com/ and the [demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) seems to work perfectly.

Make sure you are using the latest version of fullPage.js, which is now 2.5.1

Make sure as well that your browser is not getting a cached version of it. Ctrl + F5 would force the reload of those files.

Comment: You're right, it's working in http://www.browserstack.com/. my version of IE is 10.0.9200 and I'm running on vmware. Could that that have any effect ?

Comment: I believe you are probably using an older version of fullPage.js. Maybe cached in your browser.